# How does React rendering mechanism works and avoids the slow DOM manipulations?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Given that DOM manipulations are costly, how does React achieve its rendering performance?

Comment: Is jQuery an option?

Comment: I'm puzzled by where a senior front-end developer would have gotten stuck here. Was it finding all the keys in an object, or was it setting the values of the keys to empty arrays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop object properties using `for...in` loop and empty array by using `arr.length = 0`. You can also use `Array.isArray()` to first check if value is array.

```js
var myobj = {
  location : [ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' ],
  job : [ 'job1', 'job2', 'job3' ],
  other : [ 'other1', 'other2', 'other3' ]
}

for(var key in myobj) {
  if(Array.isArray(myobj[key])) myobj[key].length = 0;
}
console.log(myobj)
```

Or you can use `Object.keys()` and `forEach()` loop instead.

```js
var myobj = {
   location : [ 'item1', 'item2', 'item3' ],
   job : [ 'job1', 'job2', 'job3' ],
   other : [ 'other1', 'other2', 'other3' ]
}

Object.keys(myobj).forEach(key => myobj[key].length = 0)
console.log(myobj)
```

Comment: @George Katsanos sure.

Answer (score 0):

```js
myobj = {
  location: ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'],
  job: ['job1', 'job2', 'job3'],
  other: ['other1', 'other2', 'other3']
}
var getAllKeys = Object.keys(myobj);
getAllKeys.forEach(function(item) {
  myobj[item].length = 0;
})


console.log(myobj)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myobj = {
   location : [ item1, item2, item3 ],
   job : [ job1, job2, job3 ],
   other : [ other1, other2, other3 ]
}

for(var key in myobj){
   myobj[key] = [];
}
```